# unable to save dropdown in asp.netcore using razor pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

let me know whats wrong here , i am unable to save after selecting from drop down and clicking on save

```
<label asp-for="application.number" class="control-label"></label>
                       <select class="form-control" name="Tower">
                           <option>Select Tower</option>
                           <option>numbers</option>

                           <option>1</option>
                           <option>2</option>
                           <option>3</option>
```

i think i am getting error in below models

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tower)
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Can you show us more codes like view, model and controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to generate dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Tower",new SelectList(@ViewBag.TowerList, "TowerId","TowerName"),"Select Tower", new { @class= "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

> i am unable to save after selecting from drop down and clicking on save

You can set `value` attribute for `<option>` elements. Besides, you can refer to the following example to modify your code.

```
<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="application.number" class="control-label"></label>: @Model.application.number
    <select class="form-control" name="Tower">
        <option>Select Tower</option>
        <option>numbers</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

In page model class

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int Tower { get; set; }
    public MyClass application { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        application = new MyClass { number = 0 };
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        //code logic here to save the selected value

        application = new MyClass { number = Tower };
        return Page();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]